# Abrir un archivo .class de java en Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

En Eclipse, al cargar el archivo .CLASS, me tira el siguiente error class

> the Class File viewer cannot handle the given input ('org.eclipse.ui.ide.FileStoreEditorInput').

¿A qué se debe que salga eso? ¿qué pasos se deben seguir para corregir ese error y pueda correr programas?

Answer (score 3):

El archivo con extensión `class`. es el archivo ya compilado y no pueden ser visualizados por eclipse a menos que instales este `plugin` 
[Java Decompiler](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-decompiler-plugin-for-eclipse/) para eclipse, en la página están las instrucciones

o lo puedes hacer desde tu `consola de comandos de windows` (Descarga el .exe [Descargar](http://varaneckas.com/jad/))

- Copia el `exe` a la carpeta donde están los archivos `class`
- Anda a tu Cmd , dirigete a tu carpeta donde esta tus archivos `.class` *cd  rutadelosarchivos*
- Escribe  `jad nombrearchivo.class` y enter
- Despues de ejecutar ya tendrás un archivo con extensión `jad` que  tendrá el código java de tu archivo `class`

Answer (score 0):

El archivo .class es el resultado de compilar los archivos .java. El contenido de los archivos .class es netamente binario y no puede ser interpretado por un editor de texto (que parece ser el programa que usas para abrir el archivo).

Para ver el contenido del .class necesitas un decompilador. O, en su defecto, conocer las fuentes que originaron dicho archivo.