# COMO VER FICHEROS.CLASS EN NETBEANS

Tags: java, java-8

De un jar he extraído los ficheros.class , pero no puedo abrirlos como proyecto o 
archivo.java

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26003/abrir-un-archivo-class-de-java-en-eclipse-ide Espero que te ayude

Answer (score 1):

Esta pregunta es casi un duplicado exacto de [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/26003/57827), pero pienso que tiene un pase por el cambio de IDE.

Un archivo `.class` es un archivo compilado y traducido a Java Bytecode, el código que la JVM puede leer.

Puedes intentar usar un [decompilador](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/1177/nbjad) para Netbeans o usar uno [online](http://www.javadecompilers.com/), pero ten en cuenta que el código resultante podría no ser exactamente igual al original y que, **dependiendo de la licencia que tenga tu jar, podrías estar incurriendo en un delito.**